# rpmbuild: handle naming differences of packages in different distributions

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm writing a RPM spec file for building my software. The software depends on [Crypto++](http://cryptopp.com). Crypto++ is named differently on different distributions, for example, on OpenSUSE, I should write

```
BuildRequires: libcryptopp-devel
```

But on Fedora, it should be

```
BuildRequires: cryptopp-devel
```

Now, how can I unify the two in a single spec file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should be able to use `pkgconfig(cryptopp)`. Packages that use pkg-config can use this syntax in both [Fedora](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/PkgConfigBuildRequires/) and [SUSE](https://documentation.suse.com/sbp/all/html/SBP-RPM-Packaging/index.html#sec-improving-package), but this is a special case with pkgconfig, in other cases you'll need to use conditionals:

```
%if 0%{?fedora}
BuildRequires: cryptopp-devel
%endif

%if 0%{?suse_version}
BuildRequires: libcryptopp-devel
%endif

%if 0%{?mageia}
BuildRequires: lib64cryptopp-devel
%endif
```